# Scala Standalone WS with Authentication

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like to use the WS client from play framework without an running PlayApplication.
So I imported the WS lib only in my build.sbt with:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.3.7"
```

My example standalone application looks like:

```
object WetherWSClient extends App {

  val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
  val wsClient = new NingWSClient(builder.build());

  val holder = wsClient.url("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=80020&u=f")
  holder.withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + "token"))
  println(holder.headers) // prints an empty Map
  val futureResponse = holder.get
  futureResponse.foreach { x => println(x.body) }

  Thread.sleep(500)
  wsClient.close
}
```

Why is the header of my request holder empty? It should contain ("Authorization  -> ("Bearer " + "token"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... that's because the Scala language promotes the idea of `immutability`, and hence Keeping this spirit `WsRequestHolder` is also kind of `immutable`. So... `withHeaders` does not mutate the current `WsRequestHolder` but returns a new instance of `WsRequestHolder` which has provided headers.

Another reason for this kind of implementation is to facilitate `daisy-chaining` of calls.

So you will have to do it like this,

```
val holder = wsClient.url("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=80020&u=f")
val newHolder = holder.withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + "token"))
println(newHolder.headers)
```

Or with daisy-chaining calls,

```
val holder = wsClient.url("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=80020&u=f")
  .withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + "token"))
  .withHeaders("OtherAuthorizationHeader" -> ("Well... Daisy! " + "I got chained"))
println(holder.headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Play 2.6**

`withHeaders`is now deprecated. Taking the answer of *Sarvesh*, it looks now:

```
val holder = wsClient.url("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=80020&u=f")
val newHolder = holder.addHttpHeaders("Authorization" -> (s"Bearer $token"))
```

Or if you want to replace all Headers:

```
val newHolder = holder.withHttpHeaders("Authorization" -> (s"Bearer $token"))
```

So be aware to take now **add** if you want only add Headers! (the same behavior as `withHeaders`)